# MAPLE, How to convert a string (with my structure) to a set?

Tags: maple

i have a text file with 3 lines:

B = 2*Pi/n, true, {B, n}

a = 2*R*sin(B/2), true, {a, R, B}

P = n*a, true, {P, n, a}

i want to read this file in maple. Each line will be a set like this

```
set1 := {B = 2*Pi/n, true, {B, n}}

set2 := {a = 2*R*sin(B/2), true, {a, R, B}}

set3 := {P = n*a, true, {P, n, a}}
```

i tried to read the text file line by line (using `readline` ) and i got 3 string.

```
str1 := "B = 2*Pi/n, true, {B, n}"

str2 := "a = 2*R*sin(B/2), true, {a, R, B}"

str3 := "P = n*a, true, {P, n, a}"
```

Is there any sort way to convert these strings to sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat` to add braces to the strings and then parse them:

```
for i to 3 do
    (set || i) := parse(cat("{", (str || i), "}"));
end do;
```

If you have any control over the input file, you could do this a little more easily with the `read` command and input that is valid Maple commands:

```
set1 := {B = 2*Pi/n, true, {B, n}};
```

e.g.